How to calculate pregnant rate
I have two inputs,

the ovulation probability for one month, such as

A=[0,0,0,0,1,1,6,9,22,25,17,8,4,4,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
]/100


the pregnancy rate for a given ovulation date, such as

B=[0.03,0.06,0.09,0.18,0.27,0.33,0.42,0.2,0.08,0]

here 0.2 corresponding to ovulation day.so woman has 42% probability get pregnant 1 day before ovulation day, and has a 20% probability get pregnant at ovulation day...... now with given A and B, how to calculate the overall pregnancy probability for one month? This seems like a traditional condition probability problem, the problem is that B is a window array, not a single value.
In other words, we have the probability distribution for event A happen in one month, we also have a probability distribution for a few days for event B to happen when A happened. Now how to calculate the total probability distribution of event B?
Update: updated A for typo

Your notation is cryptic.  Presumably the components of A are a sequence of daily probabilities for a specific month.  But then how exactly does B correspond to A?  In what sense could a number like 0.2 "correspond to  ovulation day"?  What are the "ovulation days" indicated by A?  How does a 42% probability correspond to the 0.2, as your text suggests?

thanks, A is for ovulation probability, The 8th elem in B is ovulation day, i.e, if ovulation happens on Apr 8 from A, then from B we know Apr 1 has a 3% probability of getting pregnant,Apr 2 has a 6% probability...., does this make clear?

Not really: how are we supposed to figure out that the eighth component of B is the ovulation day?  How is the ovulation day determined or recognizable in these data?  Why is the length of B less than the length of A? Given that "ovulation day" appears to refer to a unique day of the month, why don't the components of A sum to unity as any valid probability vector should?

1, every day could be ovulation day, A gives a probability distribution. 2, only a limited days around ovulation day could get pregnant, you could add zero for rest days. 3 finally we need to get a pregnant probability distribution for the whole month, not a single value for a whole month.  ovulation day only represents 20% pregnancy probability, not the highest

I tried to calculate this way, for each day in A, I define a list, and multiple B, the results will be accumulated to the list C (same length with A). for example, for first non-zero items in A, 0.03, I created A1 = [0.03,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.03], B1 = [0.33,0.42,0.2,0.08,0], C1=A1*B1, repeat this for all non-zero elems in A, then sum C1 every time (align C1 in different positions in C), finally I could get a probability distribution, Max is around 25%, but not sure whether I am right

both A and B are from empirical tests, B tells us if ovulation happens on a specific day, then we have the  pregnancy distribution around this specific day, and ovulation day is right at 8th position

I"m sorry, but A clearly does not give a probability distribution: the total probability is $1.6,$ not $1$ as it needs to be.

A is around 100%, with minor shifts for decimals, such as 101. B is not necessary to get a total probability 1, B is the probability distribution if you have intercourse on each day around ovulation, for example on  ovulation day, if you have intercourse, you have 20% to getting pregnancy, instead, if you have intercourse 1 day before ovulation day, you have 42% probability to get pregnant

sorry I made a type for A, update now

@user7768436 this is still wrong, these add to 100.

I do have a /100 at the end of the list A
